# Change location of mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to move the location of a mysql database. I tried to follow the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-data-default-directory.html) and elsewhere, which say to change the "datadir" directory in "/etc/mysql/my.cnf". My problem is that "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" contains only this:

```
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

As you can see, there is not a value "datadir".

Any help is much appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a line `datadir = /path` where it says

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
```

Then restart MySQL.